# Arrange tuples nested in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, sorting, python-3.x, dictionary, tuples

I have a list of dictionaries with nested tuples like the one bellow.

```
d = [ 
('sprayed', {'paint': (4.0, None), 'car': (5.0, None), 'water': (None, 9.0), 'hose': (7.0, 6.0)}), 
('cherished', {'time': (None, 5.0), 'family': (4.0, None), 'gift': (None, 9.0)})
]
```

I want to sort it using the first item in each tuple by descending order. The outcome should look like:

```
d2 = [ 
('sprayed', {'hose': (7.0, 6.0), 'car': (5.0, None), 'paint': (4.0, 9.0), 'water': (None, 9.0)}), 
('cherished', {'family': (4.0, None), 'time': (None, 5.0), 'gift': (None, 9.0)})
]
```

I tried using:

```
s2 = []
for k, v in s:
    new_list = sorted(zip(v[::2], v[1::2]), key=lambda x: float(x[1]), reverse=True)
```

but it doesn't go through. I am certainly missing something obvious here, and I apologize in advance, but I would really appreciate if someone could point to a solution.

Comment: Dictionaries are not sorted entities. You might be looking for a `collections.OrderedDict` instead.

Comment: Also, in Python 3, `None` is not orderable: `3.0 < None` => `TypeError: unorderable types: float() < NoneType()`

Comment: One of your tuple changes too - `'hose': (7.0, 6.0)` becomes `'hose': (7.0, None)`. Is that a typo or part of the logic?

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr I was a typo, thank you for spotting it.

Comment: @Blckknght. Thank you, I will try to replace `None` for a zero!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `s` is `d`, `v` will be a dictionary, and so the expression `zip(v[::2], v[1::2])` won't work.  Dictionaries aren't sequences, and you can't slice them like you can with lists.  To get a sequence of `(key, value)` pairs for a `dict`, just do `v.items()` instead of that `zip` thing.